# rank of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

while going through the matrices and its rank,,
I found an example

matrix A
$$
\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
2 & 3 & 5 \\
3 & 4 & 7 \\
4 & 5 & 9 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

well clearly column2 and column3 are linear combinations of column1,

```
in terms of python
column1 = [ x     for x in range(1,5) ]
column2 = [ x+1   for x in range(1,5) ]
column3 = [ 2*x+1 for x in range(1,5) ]
```

similarly in R

```
column1 <- 1:4
column2 <- column1 + 1
column3 <- column1*2 + 1
```

and I have calculated the rank in both of these languages , and it turns out to be `2`,, but as per my intuition rank is the no of independent rows or columns  in a matrix , and here it is 1( column1),

Can someone, please explain where am I going wrong in my concept?

Comment: Please use [$\LaTeX{}$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because independence considers whether a column is a linear combination of other columns or not. Addition of a constant is not a linear operation. It is not equivalent to adding a multiple of other column unless you have a column like $t(1,1,1,1)$. If you create a column by multiplying by constant the vector representing the column does not change its direction. But adding a constant has a different effect. column 1 and 2 are independent as you can not represent second column as multiple of column 1.

Answer (score 1):

Column 1 and column 2 actually are independent.

Comment: isn't the column2 is a linear combination (column1 + 1)  of column 1??

Comment: No, look at the second element: $2+2\neq 3$.

Comment: I meant +1 not , adding it to itself,  1 + 1 = 2, 2 + 1 = 3, 3 + 1 = 4, 4 + 1 = 5,

Comment: Ah, but that is not how it works. You want to show that $\lambda_1 c_1 + \lambda_2 c_2 = 0$ implies $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = 0$. So you don't want that $c_1 = (-\lambda_2 / \lambda_1) c_2$. Therefore we only want to check it is not a multiple of the second column.

Comment: thanx  , @jolien , now I got it ,